# PHP templating language

Tags: php, regex

I writing simple templating language, but I have problem with nested statements. For example I using for Foreach, this regular expression:

```
preg_match('/\{foreach +\$(.*?)\}(.*?){\/foreach\}/sui', $this->content, $matches);
```

Everything work fine, but when I nesting foreach in foreach, I getting error. Because the regular expression get first opening tag but second closing tag.

> **{foreach $XY}**
>
> {foreach $YX}   **{/foreach}**
>
> {/foreach}

How can I resolve this? Thank you!

Comment: Regular expressions are typically not good at handling nested constructs.

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1225541

Comment: Regular expressions are not appropriate for parsing a language.  You have just discovered the reason why.  Also, I would discourage you from writing your own templating language, when many good solutions already exist.

Comment: Okey, but now I cannot stop writing, what is the prefered way how to do that? Parsing line by line?

Comment: @MartinPernica parsing token by token more appropiately, because you can have nested elements in a single line too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, regex are not optimal for parsing nested contexts. (Especially if you want to build a parse tree of the result.)

Never the less you can match it:

```
(?xi) {foreach \s++ \$\w++ } (?: [^{}]++ | (?R) )*+ {/foreach}
```

Could be used as:

```
preg_match_all(',{foreach \s++ \$\w++ } (?: [^{}]++ | (?R) )*+ {/foreach},xi', $str, $matches);
```

This will give you the outermost matches.

Comment: This will break if the templating language has any other constructs using braces, like `{if}`.  Advanced regex features like recursion are cool, and you could technically even build a parser with them, but to do so would be to force non-regex paradigms into regex syntax.

Comment: @dan1111, regex aren't regular. This isn't formal language theory.

Comment: I'm not talking about theory.  My point is that if you try to do something very complicated with regexes, you are going beyond their strength.

Comment: @dan1111, define "going beyond their strength". But I disagree. This isn't complicated. ;)